# jQuery.append nothing - ternary operator

Tags: jquery, append, ternary-operator

I have a web page which, depending on some boolean flags, will append various elements to a HTML page.

To make the code concise, I try to use ternary operators wherever I can - in order to save loads of `if` statements.

However, I am wondering what best practice is, when using a ternary operator, to append no elements (if that makes sense) to a dynamically created element, if my ternary operator fails. I.e.:

```
$('<div>').append(
    (myBooleanFlag ? $('<p>Some child element</p>') : /*What here???*/)
);
```

Three solutions I have are as follows, but I do not know which one is the best and whether I should avoid any:

Appending an empty jQuery object - which seems the right way to do it, since it means both outcomes are the jQuery object type:

```
$('<div>').append(
    (myBooleanFlag ? $('<p>Some child element</p>') : $())
);
```

An empty string, which seems wrong anyway since they're not the same type:

```
$('<div>').append(
    (myBooleanFlag ? $('<p>Some child element</p>') : '')
);
```

Append `null` - which seems logical, but I do not want to cause any type of error:

```
$('<div>').append(
    (myBooleanFlag ? $('<p>Some child element</p>') : null)
);
```

So which is best would you say?

Comment: use an `if` stmt like `if(myBooleanFlag ){$('<div>').append(
    ('<p>Some child element</p>')
);`

Comment: Honestly, I believe an `if` statement would be far more readable than `(foo ? $("<bar />") : undefined)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, I am wondering what best practice is, when using a ternary operator, to append no elements

Best practice would be not to use a ternary operator for a situation where it's not appropriate. If you don't know what goes in the third operand, it's clear that the situation isn't a good fit for using a ternary operator.

While you *can* use a blank string:

```
$('<div>').append(
    (myBooleanFlag ? '<p>Some child element</p>' : '')
);
```

...it's much clearer, just as concise, and more efficient to use the `if`:

```
if (myBooleanFlag) {
    $('<div>').append('<p>Some child element</p>');
}
```

I hesitate to mention it, but another JavaScript idiom that applies here is using the `&&` operator and the expression statement:

```
myBooleanFlag && $('<div>').append('<p>Some child element</p>');
```

This is possible because in JavaScript, an expression can be a statement. Since `&&` is short-circuited, if `myBooleanFlag` is falsey, the `append` call is not triggered.

Some people really love that syntax. Others find it hard to read and debug. It's basically a hidden `if` in this form:

```
if (myBooleanFlag) $('<div>').append('<p>Some child element</p>');
```

...which falls afoul of all the usual coding convention things about always using `{}` with conditionals, etc. But again, it's a style thing.

---

Side note: You can just use the string in the positive case above, no need to use `$(...)` on it before passing it to `append`, so I've left it out in the above.

Side note 2: There's no need to put parens around the conditional when passing it as an argument to a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result =  myBooleanFlag ? $('<p>Some child element</p>') : null;

$('<div>').append(result);
```

Comment: Well, this is longer than an `if` statement, less readable, and ends up calling `$()` and `append()` for nothing if the condition is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use an `if` statement instead:

```
if(myBooleanFlag ){
    $('<div>').append('<p>Some child element</p>');
}
```

Comment: he ask about ternary opeartor

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest a ternary operator here.

Whatever is the value of your `myBooleanFlag` you will always call the `append()` method, even when it is not necessary at all. So why would you call the jQuery function twice even if you have nothing to append?

A straight `if` statement is enough for your purpose (and it's more readable)

```
if (myBooleanFlag){
    $('<div>').append('...');
}
```

---

if you want an alternative shorter syntax (even shorter than the ternary operator) you may instead use this expression/statement

```
myBooleanFlag && $('<div>').append('...');
```

the `append()` will be executed only if `myBooleanFlag` is `true`, so jQuery won't be called when the flag is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

1) appending div with **$()**, will give error due to you give no object inside bracket

2) appending div with **''** is the correct way .

3) appending div with null is not correct way because **null** is also consider as string

so use second one